# Why does mouse down block repainting of a component?

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I am trying to create a custom component that captures mouse events, especially MouseMove.

I derive from `TWinControl`, but I have also tried with `TGraphicControl`, `TCustomControl`, `TTrackBar`, etc.

My problem is when I hold down the mouse on the component, it is not being repainted.

The `Paint()` method is not called until I release the mouse button, even if I call `Invalidate()`.

A TrackBar is the closest component I want to make.  You select the tick, and move it around with the mouse.  But you do not have to release the mouse to see the tick move at the same time (the component is drawn again).

If I directly call `Paint()`, it works, but the background is not erased.

What am I missing?

EDIT :
I tried again and i confirm if i held the mouse down, Invalidate(); call are take in account only when i release the mouse.
Try your self with my code below, paint is only call on release :

```
__fastcall TMyCustomComponent::TMyCustomComponent(TComponent* Owner)
    : TCustomTransparentControl(Owner)
{
    mValue = 0;
}

void __fastcall TMyCustomComponent::MouseDown(System::Uitypes::TMouseButton Button, System::Classes::TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y)
{
    if (Button == mbLeft)
        {
        mValueStart = 0;        
        }
}

void __fastcall TMyCustomComponent::MouseMove(System::Classes::TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y)
{       
    Invalidate();       
}

void __fastcall TMyCustomComponent::Paint(void)
{
    TGraphicControl::Paint();   
    Canvas->Font->Name = "Arial";
    Canvas->Font->Size = 8;
    Canvas->Font->Style = TFontStyles() << fsBold;
    Canvas->Font->Color = clInfoText;
    Canvas->Brush->Color = clInfoBk;
    Canvas->FillRect(TRect(0, 0, 104, 21));
    mValue++;
    Canvas->TextOut(0, 2, AnsiString(mValue));
    Canvas->Brush->Color = clBtnShadow; 
}
```

Comment: "The `Paint()` method is not called until I release the mouse button" is suggestive of the current paint being keyed on button up.

Comment: Please show your actual code. You are likely just not handling the mouse correctly.  As a test, I created a custom control that is able to repaint itself while the mouse is held down on it.  `Paint()` and `Invalidate()` worked fine. MouseDown does not normally block message processing, unless you are doing something in your code to block it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, please see my code, what is more correct ? If i could see your code too, because i really do not find how to do what i want. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Maypeur you should not be incrementing `mValue` inside of `Paint()`, that belongs in `MouseMove()` before calling `Invalidate()`. And `MouseDown()` should be calling `Invalidate()` after resetting `mValue`. And `Paint()` should be calling `TCustomTransparentControl::Paint()` instead of `TGraphicControl::Paint()`

Comment: MS-Windows only: the paint message is a pseudo message and is only sent to the application when then message queue is empty (of other messages). Holding the mouse button down spams the queue with mouse messages.

Comment: Does it would say i have to handle WndProc, intercept WM_MOUSEDOWN and send WM_PAINT manualy ?

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for your reponse, but this is only for the test, anyway i persist, the invalidate in MouseMove do nothing until i release the mouse, Richard Critten explanation is concurring, anyway TTrackBar works well in the same way without redraw problem but i do not have the source code !

Comment: @RichardCritten simply holding the mouse down does not spam the message queue. And as I stated earlier, I was able to create an example that processed paint requests while holding the mouse down (I used a timer to Invalidate the control, triggering paint messages, and `WM_TIMER` is another synthesized message that is only generated when the message queue is empty), so clearly the message queue was able to clear out without being heavily spammed.

Comment: @Maypeur the VCL source code is provided with the IDE. But `TTrackBar` is just a thin wrapper for a [Win32 Trackbar control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/trackbar-controls). All of the *real* work is inside the OS, not the VCL.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for the info, but please past your code, because it really doesn't work for me after many hours of searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works fine for me:

```
__fastcall TMyCustomComponent::TMyCustomComponent(TComponent* Owner)
    : TCustomTransparentControl(Owner)
{
    mValue = 0;
    InterceptMouse = true; // <-- needed for TCustomTransparentControl to trigger Mouse...() methods!
}

void __fastcall TMyCustomComponent::MouseDown(System::Uitypes::TMouseButton Button, System::Classes::TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y)
{
    if (Button == mbLeft)
    {
        mValue = 0;
        Invalidate();
    }
    TCustomTransparentControl::MouseDown(Button, Shift, X, Y);
}

void __fastcall TMyCustomComponent::MouseMove(System::Classes::TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y)
{
    ++mValue;
    Invalidate();
    TCustomTransparentControl::MouseMove(Shift, X, Y);
}

void __fastcall TMyCustomComponent::Paint()
{
    TCustomTransparentControl::Paint();
    Canvas->Font->Name = "Arial";
    Canvas->Font->Size = 8;
    Canvas->Font->Style = TFontStyles() << fsBold;
    Canvas->Font->Color = clInfoText;
    Canvas->Brush->Color = clInfoBk;
    Canvas->FillRect(TRect(0, 0, ClientWidth, ClientHeight));
    Canvas->TextOut(0, 2, String(mValue));
    Canvas->Brush->Color = clBtnShadow;
}
```

Pressing down the left mouse button resets `mValue` to 0 and paints it. And moving the mouse around the control increments `mValue` and paints it, whether the mouse button is held down or not.